# How to export model for use in Unity with correct UV map?

Tags: texturing, uv, unity

I have model with proper (not beautiful) UV map. It looks like this. The texture is where it should be:
[image: texture in Blender]

Then I export the model to .dae (and I tried all other export type, that Unity gets. I have the same problem at every file type).
In unity it looks like this:
[image: Exact same model in Unity]

I do not use mirror modifier or anything, yet it looks like the UV map in unity only applies on one half of the model. Where it goes wrong? What I am missing about Unity? (I just started to use it)

The .blend file:
[image]

Comment: Could you share an extract of your blend file (http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) ?

Comment: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1492/ I edit the post too.

Comment: I dont know unity (so I wont post an answer), but your UV map is out of the texture : https://i.gyazo.com/171c814aa78bcad8179621a566688666.png. Can that be the cause ?

Comment: a guess : or unity does not support it, or there is an option for that in unity ?

Comment: Well... you were right. That was the problem. Seems I got lazy in Blender as it supports resizing UV outside of texture (so it repeats and smaller on the model). Unity does not support UV overflow it seems. Thank you!

Comment: Could you please give these elements as an answer to your question (in the answer part) ? (that can help BSE) Thanks

Comment: I am right on it!

Answer (score 1):

So as it turned out in comments, while in Blender I can make the UV map bigger than the texture to make texture smaller on the model like this:
[image]

in Unity it simply checks for the UV map inside the texture. As you can see half of the boat was outside the texture (it was accidentally sized it like that) half of the texture was wrong in Unity.